# How to invalidate CDN URL which contains '{' in query string

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cdn, cache-invalidation, aws-cdn

Below is request url which contains query string param, that I have successfully cached using CDN. But I am unable to purge the request url or invalidate it from cache.

url - /search/name?parent=true&filter={"age":5,"skip":0,"where":{"address.pincode":"403003"},"include":["name", "surname", "address"]}

error message - "Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths."

Comment: I don't know if this helps but have you tried URL encoding the filter param? So after filter= would be: %7B%22age%22%3A5%2C%22skip%22%3A0%2C%22where%22%3A%7B%22address.pincode%22%3A%22403003%22%7D%2C%22include%22%3A%5B%22name%22%2C%20%22surname%22%2C%20%22address%22%5D%7D

Comment: Use `window.encodeURI` to encode the url.

Comment: @funkizer I tried with url encoding but that invalidate other form of request. so that is also not working.